# VS Code: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run"

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to use VS code in a windows 10 machine to debug a c program.

When I press F5, the debug console, come out the error message below

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="args",value="2>CON 1>CON <CON"
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". 
Error creating process {my program path}\testing.exe, (error 5).
The program {my program path}\testing.exe has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

I had try:

1. reinstall the [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)
2. reinstall the VS Code(ver 1.53.0)
3. Add the MinGW to Environment path
4. check other no error computer that our launch.json and task.json file content are the same

the only thing that I found different with the no error computer is the command in terminal

#### Have error

```
'c:\Users\{my name}\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.2.0\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-woaq1zfx.ino' 
'--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-cktvzb1f.ldz' 
'--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.eauncher.exe' 
'--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ousjkx2v.fa4' 
'--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-3zwxjow2.lxd' 
'--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-woaq1zfx.ino' 
'--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-cktvzb1f.ldz' 
'--dbgamming> Exe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' 
'--interpreter=mi
```

#### No error

```
'c:\Users\{my name}\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.2.0\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' 
'--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-dbis1iss.4uo' 
'--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-2k2qns13.5jp' 
'--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-ixytwn1h.hzm' 
'--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-kqpv2wcw.1oc' 
'--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' 
'--interpreter=mi'
```

Comment: `gdb` is very pedantic regarding that it must be in the environment path when you start VSC. Start VSC from a terminal where you know that `gbd` (no path) is a recognized command

Comment: Thanks for comment.
I restart my computer, and start the gdb.exe with only `gdb` keyword, I can enter the gdb, however the error still happen.

Comment: what if you start gdb yourself from the command line to debug the executable, calling your program `test____` is never a good idea unless you write the unix command `test`

Comment: Sorry, I found the reason, the MCAfee recognize the output as virus. Problem solve after I uninstall MCAfee.
Thank you for time!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, the MCAfee recognize the output as virus. Problem solve after I uninstall MCAfee