# Visual Studio Code and Cygwin is not debugging. And have a problem with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I just started coding(?), I think... I was setting up Visual Studio Code for C programming and I was using Cygwin.

I'm writing a single Hello World print code. Yes, I can compile it with Ctrl+Shift+B. But when I tried the debugging with F5, it's giving this error down there;

```
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 9.2-1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Error creating process /cygdrive/c/Users/EM&ES BİLGİSAYAR/cworkings/fckworld/fckworld.exe, (error 193).
The program 'c:\Users\EM&ES BİLGİSAYAR\cworkings\fckworld\fckworld.exe' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

I was using gdb v10 but after 6 hours of researching on the internet, I downgraded it to V9. Nothing is changed except "error 2" to "error 193".

Comment: Just in case what's the visual Studio version? May be relevant.

Comment: Also "Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64." This may be relevant. Is the assumption made by the computer correct?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [c - VS Code: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084499/vs-code-unexpected-gdb-output-from-command-exec-run) .

Comment: Looks like there are some other questions with other issues too (without answers) [VS Code: GDB debug: ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run" - Stack Overflow]([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69038667)) // [Setting up VS Code for C using Cygwin64 Compiler and Debugger on Windows (ERROR: Unable to start debugging) - Stack Overflow]([2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69666559)) // [c++ - VSCode LLDB on MacOS error when starting debugging session - Stack Overflow]([3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67270447))